# Best way to store data in mobile app

Tags: android, ios, mobile, storage, store

I am curious as to the best way to store data on an application for both storing through updates and readability inside of the app.

Basically I have a game I am building, and it has levels, I need to check if the user has completed the level yet, if they have then it can unlock the next level if not, leave the next level locked.

So I need to store a file on the phone that I can refer back to to see if the level has been beaten or not.

I have done some research and found I can use Shared Preferences, Internal Data Storage or External Data Storage. I was leaning towards External Data Storage until a friend pointed out that people wipe their SD cards quite often to put new music, videos and pictures on. But if I use Internal Data Storage then the data is lost when I update the application with new features and levels? So would Shared Preferences be the best way to go?

Please would you give me some advice on what is the best way to store the data that would be easiest to read at a later stage and how would I do that? Would I store a list of the levels beat and then cross check the level to that list?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where did you read the "the data is lost when I update the application"? I've never heard that before (genuinely curious, not being a dick).

Comment: How much data, items and bytes?

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using CoreData or SQLite on iOS for storing app's data. XML is quite cumbersome to play with as it needs to be parsed every time you load it, hence it is not very optimised. On iOS, we have NSUserDefaults which does provide storage feature but it is recommended for storing less amount of data.

Comment: Using sqlite will make the app more portable between Android and iOS worlds. I agree using XML is cumbersome. Learning to use SQL will also be a good skill to acquire.

Answer (score 1):

If you use internal data storage or Shared Preferences, data is NOT wiped on app update (or even OS update). It's only wiped if the user uninstalls the app, "clears data" on your app, or wipes their entire device. Shared Preferences are effectively a file inside the app's internal data storage location, managed by the OS (and no other apps have access to it).

It sounds like for your use case, Shared Preferences are the way to go. That's exactly what they're intended for. As for how exactly to structure the keys/values that you store, that's entirely up to your app... I would say possibly have keys like "passed_level_1", etc. Unfortunately, Shared Preferences does not support arrays (neither for keys, nor for values).

Also keep in mind that on rooted devices, users can have access to that data (even though it's not in plain-text format). So if that's a security concern, consider using encryption or some other type of secure storage. Using external storage has this concern as well, even more so, since all users have access to it, not just rooted users.

Comment: Oh okay, I was under the impression (as said somewhere in Thenewboston's youtube android development series that the content would be lost using Internal Data Storage when you update the app

Comment: I've never heard of that. Nothing should be lost when upgrading to a new version of the app, as long as the new version has the same signature as the old version (otherwise Android won't let the user upgrade and they have to uninstall the old version first, which WILL wipe internal app data and preferences). But yeah, in the normal case, nothing is lost.

Answer (score 0):

In my game I save that information on a XML stored on the Internal Data Storage, so the data will be lost only if the user uninstall the application or chose to "clear data", but in my case I have a lot of information to save, like stars, points and some bonus information, if you need to save only the level, I think the SharedPreferences is the best choice...
 
A last resource is to save this information in a webservice, but I don't think this is the case.